# Changing App Installer to Flashable Installer?

Tags: applications, apk, zip

Hello There Everyone!,

To clarify the title...

Is there a way to change, modify, convert, etc... an App Installer (.apk) to a Flashable Installer (.zip).

I'm not referring to just creating a zip to simply copy the apk file to its desired directory but, to either install the app as a new app and/or upgrade an existing one in the same/similar fashion as would an apk itself would be installed.

I tried to search around and the results aren't specific to what I'm asking and reflects the copying of the apk file rather than the installing of it.

I hope that I had explained this okay via text... :-)

Thank you very much for your time and understanding with this question!

~Ibuprophen

Comment: Copying it to the appropriate directory in `/data/app` does install it on next boot. Unfortunately "appropriate directory" isn't always easy to figure out.

Comment: Installing APK Files just copies them to data and sets up the working directory for it in data/data ... It would be exactly the same as making a zip that copies the apk to desired location, except you'd need to create the folders under data/data in the flashable zip.. `mkdir /data/data/com.example.app`

Comment: Tested and confirmed working on LOS 14.1: installing e.g. OctoDroid is simply a matter of creating the `com.gh4a-1` directory (name comes from the app's package name plus the `-1` suffix) under `/data/app`, uid/gid == `1000`, mode == `755`. Then, drop the app's APK inside that directory, rename it to `base.apk`, set uid/gid to `1000` and mode to `644`. Finally, reboot and Android will handle lib extraction, app uid/gid creation and so on. If it works for you, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: The above would only work for <= Android 7.1. Android 8+ hashed the folder names.

Comment: @AndyYan Could you make an example?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d8HU.png). I honestly don't get why they decided to change this, killed my flashable zip as well.

Comment: @AndyYan An unprivileged user with a terminal emulator could extract the .apk file pertaining to a certain app, if they knew the app's package name, but they couldn't list the contents of `/data/app`. Making .apk extractions harder is what comes to mind.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman They wouldn't be able to pull anything off `/data` without su privilege in the first place; with su they'd be able to do whatever they want, and the random folder name is just a nuisance. // Also, I don't have a device that's not running LineageOS, but considering how LOS always complied well with Google standards, I'm assuming that this behavior should be universal. I can't find reliable documentation on this however, all I have are my own experience and one or two forum posts claiming the same.

Comment: @AndyYan As I said before, the permissions of a `base.apk` file are `644`, effectively making it extractable by anyone. Still, the lack of docs is somewhat worrying.

Comment: Thank you all for your input but, I know about moving (or creating such) the app to the system directory and even creating a flashable zip to do this but, that wasn't a actual question itself. I have a personal apk file I had created and it does install fine within the user apps just by selecting and installing using the Android Package Installer. I was wondering how/where I can have an individual (with Root of course) the ability to install the app using the same Android Package Installer method and it installing as a system app instead of a user app.